# How to get all the records in a dropdown list?

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list that filters the records by category, but I need the "-- Filter by category --" option to act as the "view all", whereby all the records are returned.

This is in C# .NET.  I don't expect it to be too difficult, but its just stumping me right now.

Here is the code-behind for the method:

```
protected void PopulateCategories()
{
    category myCategory = new category();
    category[] myCategoryList = myCategory.Listing("title ASC");

    ddlCategories.Items.Add("-- Filter by category --");

    foreach (category category in myCategoryList)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(category.title, category.category_id);
        ddlCategories.Items.Add(item);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what your data source is, and how it reacts to the `category.category_id` value, you should put a value as part of your "-- Filter by category --" entry...

```
ddlCategories.Items.Add(New ListItem("-- Filter by category --", "-1"));
```

Then when you use the `ddlCategories.SelectedValue` (or however you use it) make sure that if the value is `-1` then return everything

Comment: I tried adding it, but it tells me there is no overload for ddlCategories that takes two argumenets.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Peter - most likely is that you've just added another parameter, and not used the `New ListItem`

Comment: @Peter, have you updated the line exactly as I have above, or just added `, "-1"` to your existing line? If you pass a string directly into `DropDownList.Item.Add` then that string will be used both as the display title and the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tag. In order to have both a display title and a different `value` you must use a `New ListItem(text,value)`

Comment: Yeah, I rushed that, sorry.  So not I just put it in an `if statement`, right?

Comment: @Peter, no worries :-)  I'm not sure I understand... what you do with that `-1` value (or whatever you decide to use) is down to your particular data-source that is used to drive whatever you're filtering

Comment: Well, I added that line of code, but I just want it to return all the records if it is selected, otherwise do the part that is already existing.

Comment: Sorry @Peter, but you have given us absolutely no information other than the population of this "filter" dropdown - without knowing what you are doing with the selected value of the dropdown it is exceeding difficult to help. Put simply, whatever you are using the filter against, if the selected value is `-1` then do not filter! I don't want to come across as harsh, but that is the reality of the situation

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your form more intuitive, you may want to populate the dropdown as shown below:

```
ddlCategories.Items.Add(new ListItem("- View all categories -", "-1"));

foreach (category category in myCategoryList)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem("View category: " + category.title, category.category_id);
    ddlCategories.Items.Add(item);            
}
```

**Then, to answer your question, create 2 data access methods: #1 for retrieving all rows, #2 for retrieving rows filtered by the chosen category.**

```
public DataTable GetData(int categoryId)
{
  if(categoryId <= 0)
  {
    // #1
    return CatProvider.FindAll(); // Ex. SELECT * FROM table_cats;
  }
  else
  {
    // #2
    return CatProvider.FindByCategoryId(categoryId); // Ex. SELECT * from table_cats where id_category = @id_category;
  }
}
```

*However, I would consider using checkboxes instead (1 for each category), so the user can select any permutation of either all categories, just 1 category, or any combination of multiple categories.*

(That's about all I can suggest for now based on the info you provided.)